# Trying to download miner but Google Chrome marks them as malicious/malware

Tags: mining-software, malware

First I tried [GUIMiner-scrypt](http://guiminer.org/guiminer-scrypt.html) and then [cgminer-3.9.0-windows.zip](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.9/)

Both archives are marked as malicious in Google Chrome. I googled and have not found articles about that. Do other people get such warnings while downloading miner?

[image: miner malware warning]

**UPDATE**

My links are 2 top google results
@TinS gave another download link and file is name is same `guiminer-scrypt_win32_binaries_v0.04.zip` but size is different.

One file is marked as malicious by Google Chrome and another not.

Comment: I think the tag "malware" covers it sufficiently and we don't need a "malicious" tag additionally.

Comment: Google Chrome tells `malicious` I added `malware` myself just because there is such tag.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant: "malware" by itself is recognizable and descriptive. On the other hand I don't see how "malicious" could ever stand as the only tag of a question, as it could refer to anything.

Comment: The first site has fine print that says says "This site is not the official page of the software." I'd be very suspicious of that download. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=150331.0 seems to be a more reputable place.

Comment: The one I downloaded from your link is not marked as malware. My links are top results in google and google mark then as suspicious. Also virustotal give [18 warnings](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/2b81c045f6e073e65b7ff13327e7293c5bd8fbca129f1fd917ad9e9112037170/analysis/)

@TimS. Thanks

Comment: I'd bet the reason Chrome marks it as malicious is the same some anti-viruses mark scrypt miners as malicious: since scrypt can be mined with CPU, botnets galore attach a CPU-scrypt-miner as payload to put the computers they control to mine for their manager...

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, Google has added this feature into Chrome : http://www.pcworld.com/article/2059579/googles-chrome-will-automatically-block-malware.html

But it seems that sometimes Chrome marked as malicious something which is not. If you have downloaded it from the official website you don't have to worry.

If you want to be sure you can get a checksum of the file (there is not the checksum on the official page so just ask someone you trust).

Comment: I know this `feature`. But there is still a risk that some redirect done by some admin who works on my ISP who tries to put malware on miners PC. If it is a mistake then every other user will get error notification as me and I expect to see it all over internet but I google and have not found people complaining on such issue.

Comment: What about the checksum ? If it's the correct checksum you can be sure it's only your Chrome.

Comment: "If you have downloaded it from the official website you don't have to worry." Poor advice. Projects and companies are often bought by criminals specifically for the purpose of leveraging previous credibility to spread malware. CGMiner has not been maintained for YEARS.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why to Google Chrome appears some files as malicious e.g.

1. Is the host site known and trusted?
2. Can the identity of the host site be verified? (e.g. SSL certificate, https)
3. Can the the identity of the file's publisher be verified? (e.g. via code signing certificate)
4. Is the file known and trusted?

But as main reason we can consider not using `SSL certificates` or `https` url.

Even though you can discard this pop-up and download the file I would recommend you to scan it through antivirus program.

From my experience I can say that the cg-miner is safe to use! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think answerers are missing is this is not the "keep or discard" version - this is "it has been discarded and you can't do anything about it" issue. So with a file we know is valid - we can't do anything to retrieve it off the top.

Go to your downloads tab on chrome - it'll show you the error again with an option to discard it or keep the file anyway.